# How to design a type safe message API in Java?

Tags: java, api

I have a Java client which wants to communicate with a device through messages over serial communication. The client should be able to use a clean API, abstracting the ugly details of the serial communication. The client can send many types of messages through that API and gets responses. I'm searching for advice which way is best to implement this API.

For simplicity, say we have only two message types: `HelloMessage` which triggers a `HelloResponse` and `InitMessage` which triggers an `InitResponse` (in reality, there are many more)

Designing the API (that is, the Java abstraction of the device) I could have:

One method per message type:

```
public class DeviceAPI {
  public HelloResponse sendHello(HelloMessage){...}
  public InitResponse sendInit(InitMessage){...}
  ... and many more message types ....
```

This is nicely type safe. (It could also be many times the same `send()` method, overloaded, but that's about the same). But it is very explicit, and not very flexible - we cannot add messages without modification of the API.

I could also have a single send method, which takes all message types:

```
class HelloMessage implements Message
class HelloResponse implements Response   
...
public class DeviceAPI {
  public Response send(Message msg){
    if(msg instanceof HelloMessage){
       // do the sending, get the response
       return theHelloResponse
    } else if(msg instanceof ...
```

This simplifies the API (only one method) and allows for additional Message types to be added later without changing the API. At the same time, it requires the Client to check the Response type and cast it to the right type.

Client code:

```
DeviceAPI api = new DeviceAPI();
HelloMessage msg = new HelloMessage();
Response rsp = api.send(msg);
if(rsp instanceOf HelloResponse){
    HelloResponse hrsp = (HelloResponse)rsp;
    ... do stuff ...
```

This is ugly in my opinion.

What do you recommend? Are there other approaches which give cleaner results?

References welcome! How did others solve this?

Comment: Would a parametrized type with an enum be a possibility? Or is this not possible (at all).

Comment: You check the type of "Response" and you cast then the HelloMessage. It seems grotesque. Anyway, you can hide the "instanceOf" and the "casting" operations in the implementation classes.

Comment: I don't think having to check types is ugly at all, this is likely how I'd implement it too. If you don't want this, I think the right spot to reconsider is your model; what makes it necessary for these responses to be different objects? Can't they be generics, for example?

Comment: @MarkTielemans The messages have many similarities, but also many differences. Say the HelloResponse contains the serial number of the device. I would like the HelloResponse object to have a getSerialNumber() method. How could I achieve this with generics?

Comment: @arjacsoh Sorry, that was a typo. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in type-safe (and extensible) way using generics:

```
public interface MessageType {    
    public static final class HELLO implements MessageType {};
}

public interface Message<T extends MessageType> {
    Class<T> getTypeClass();
}

public interface Response<T extends MessageType> {
}
```

---

```
public class HelloMessage implements Message<MessageType.HELLO> {

    private final String name;

    public HelloMessage(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<MessageType.HELLO> getTypeClass() {
        return MessageType.HELLO.class;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

public class HelloResponse implements Response<MessageType.HELLO> {

    private final String name;

    public HelloResponse(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return "hello " + name;
    }

}
```

---

```
public interface MessageHandler<T extends MessageType, M extends Message<T>, R extends Response<T>> {
    R handle(M message);
}

public class HelloMessageHandler 
    implements MessageHandler<MessageType.HELLO, HelloMessage, HelloResponse> {
    @Override
    public HelloResponse handle(final HelloMessage message) {
        return new HelloResponse(message.getName());
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Device {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private final Map<Class<? extends MessageType>, MessageHandler> handlers =
        new HashMap<Class<? extends MessageType>, MessageHandler>();

    public <T extends MessageType, M extends Message<T>, R extends Response<T>> 
        void registerHandler(
            final Class<T> messageTypeCls, final MessageHandler<T, M, R> handler) {
        handlers.put(messageTypeCls, handler);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends MessageType, M extends Message<T>, R extends Response<T>> 
        MessageHandler<T, M, R> getHandler(final Class<T> messageTypeCls) {
        return handlers.get(messageTypeCls);
    }


    public <T extends MessageType, M extends Message<T>, R extends Response<T>> 
        R send(final M message) {
        MessageHandler<T, M, R> handler = getHandler(message.getTypeClass());
        R resposnse = handler.handle(message);
        return resposnse;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Device device = new Device();
        HelloMessageHandler helloMessageHandler = new HelloMessageHandler();
        device.registerHandler(MessageType.HELLO.class, helloMessageHandler);

        HelloMessage helloMessage = new HelloMessage("abhinav");
        HelloResponse helloResponse = device.send(helloMessage);
        System.out.println(helloResponse.getGreeting());
    }
}
```

---

To add support for a new message type, implement `MessageType` interface to create a new message type, implement `Message`, `Response` and `MessageHandler` interfaces for the new `MessageType` class and register the handler for the new message type by calling `Device.registerHandler`.

Comment: Very clean solution, thanks! (very similar to Skiwi's). After a bit of tweaking I also could remove the getTypeClass() method from Message. You can access that same information with message.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0].getActualTypeArguments() (needs some casting to ParameterizedType in there somewhere)

Answer (score 2):

I've got a fully working example now of what you want:

To define the types of messages:

```
public interface MessageType {
    public static class INIT implements MessageType { }
    public static class HELLO implements MessageType { }
}
```

Base `Message` and `Response` classes:

```
public class Message<T extends MessageType> {

}
```

---

```
public class Response<T extends MessageType> {

}
```

Create custom init messages and responses:

```
public class InitMessage extends Message<MessageType.INIT> {
    public InitMessage() {
        super();
    }

    public String getInit() {
        return "init";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class InitResponse extends Response<MessageType.INIT> {
    public InitResponse() {
        super();
    }

    public String getInit() {
        return "init";
    }
}
```

Create custom hello messages and responses:

```
public class HelloMessage extends Message<MessageType.HELLO> {
    public HelloMessage() {
        super();
    }

    public String getHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class HelloResponse extends Response<MessageType.HELLO> {
    public HelloResponse() {
        super();
    }

    public String getHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

The `DeviceAPI`:

```
public class DeviceAPI {
    public <T extends MessageType, R extends Response<T>, M extends Message<T>> R send(M message) {
        if (message instanceof InitMessage) {
            InitMessage initMessage = (InitMessage)message;
            System.out.println("api: " + initMessage.getInit());
            return (R)(new InitResponse());
        }
        else if (message instanceof HelloMessage) {
            HelloMessage helloMessage = (HelloMessage)message;
            System.out.println("api: " + helloMessage.getHello());
            return (R)(new HelloResponse());
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it does require an `instanceof`-tree, but you need that to handle what kind of message it is.

And a working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DeviceAPI api = new DeviceAPI();

    InitMessage initMsg = new InitMessage();
    InitResponse initResponse = api.send(initMsg);
    System.out.println("client: " + initResponse.getInit());

    HelloMessage helloMsg = new HelloMessage();
    HelloResponse helloResponse = api.send(helloMsg);
    System.out.println("client: " + helloResponse.getHello());
}
```

Output:

```
api: init
client: init
api: hello
client: hello
```

**UPDATE**: Added example on how to get input from the messages the client wants to send.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Suppose the responses carry different information, how could I access this?

Comment: @Philipp Working on that at the moment, you want to be able to use something like `InitMessage` instead of `Message<MessageType.INIT>`.

Comment: @Philipp I've got my final working example now. I hope this is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Philipp And included a working example on how to read input values from the messages.

Comment: That's a clever way of doing it. All the casting is hidden! Thanks for developing it. Nonetheless I believe Abhinav Sarkar's solution is even superior, as it replace the instanceOf ladder by a Map of handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a system of message handlers, and your DeviceAPI could choose which handler is suitable for the incoming message; and delegate it to the appropriate message handler:

```
class DeviceAPI {

private List<Handler> msgHandlers = new ArrayList<Handler>();

public DeviceAPI(){
    msgHandlers.add(new HelloHandler());
            //Your other message handlers can be added
}

public Response send(Message msg) throws Exception{
    for (Handler handler : msgHandlers) {
        if (handler.canHandle(msg)){
            return handler.handle(msg);
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("No message handler defined for " + msg);
}
}
```

The HelloHandler would look like:

```
 interface Handler<T extends Message, U extends Response> {
    boolean canHandle(Message message);
    U handle(T message);
 }


class HelloHandler implements Handler<HelloMessage, HelloResponse> {

@Override
public boolean canHandle(Message message) {
    return message instanceof HelloMessage;
}

@Override
public HelloResponse handle(HelloMessage message) {
    //Process your message
    return null;
}
}
```

Ditto for your other messages. I'm sure you could make it more elegant, but the idea still remains the same - donot have one monster method with ifs; instead use polymorphism.

Comment: I like the idea: that's more of a callback approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is ugly at all:

```
if(rsp instanceOf HelloResponse){
    HelloResponse hrsp = (HelloResponse)rsp;
    ...
else if ...
```

as long as you don't have like 100 different responses. You can encapsulate many kind of responses in one, depending on the data they have. For example:

```
class GenericResponse{
   private String message;
   private int responseType;
   ...
}
```

I have developed some multiplayer games and this is a good way to do it.
In case you have too many different types of messages, you just can use generic java types, like the example of skiwi above.

hope it helps

Comment: I have been taught that instanceOf ladders are code smell. Which is why I'm looking for a more OO approach. Maybe with a visitor pattern?